# As my apology and thanks, please don't hesitate to request of me paywalled resources

Tags: discussion

I'll scrutinize [What should we do with low-quality etymology questions?](https://latin.meta.stackexchange.com/q/414/37) that's undoubtedly directed at me. I apologise for miffing some of you and thank you very much for all your succor.

As talk is cheap though, I can proffer to provide paywalled resources. As you have seen, I can access the OED online and  [*Oxford Latin Dictionary* (2012 2 ed)](https://www.amazon.ca/Oxford-Latin-Dictionary-Dictionaries/dp/0199580316).