# What semantic notions underlie haemophilia and 'A constitutional (usually hereditary) tendency to bleeding'?

Tags: discussion

Why was https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/11345/37 downvoted at least 4 times? Can we please undelete and reopen it?

> I actually think this is a very good question. – [fdb](https://latin.stackexchange.com/users/324/fdb) [Aug 18 at 16:45](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/11345/what-semantic-notions-underlie-haemophilia-and-a-constitutional-usually-heredi#comment21046_11345)

Answer (score 5):

Thanks for asking!
I will try to keep this answer objective, reflecting what seems to be a community opinion based on the various votes.

### Undeletion in general

All users with enough reputation (I think 4000 but I could be mistaken) can vote to undelete a question, and so can the question's owner.
That is the way things should go:
The community votes up and down and about closing and deleting and reopening and undeleting.
The reputation thresholds vary.

I think the decisions on these things should be made by the community, not unilaterally by the moderators.
A moderator's vote takes effect immediately, and because we can only act, not vote, we act carefully.
In this case the moderators did nothing; the question was deleted automatically by the system and it was just about to be closed (4/5 votes).
It is unlikely that we will act to undelete either.

However, user moderation is not fully functional on a small site like ours.
For example, we have 20 users with at least 4000 reputation, and 5 of them are needed to undelete a question.
(I think the number five should be reduced to, say, three on a small site, but that is out of our hands.)
What I have done on several occasions is to wait for other users to vote and only cast my vote when I see that there is support for the decision.
That way it is not unilateral but gets done.
I am ready to exercise that here as well, provided that there are votes to undelete or comments here supporting it and not much opposition.

However, manual undeletion will not help much.
Unless the score improves or an answer emerges, the question still qualifies for automatic deletion and will be redeleted soon.

### The specific question

Different users have different reasons to vote down and vote to close.
I cannot tell why they found it unsuitable for the site, but they did.

You previously [asked for help in asking such questions](https://latin.meta.stackexchange.com/q/412/79).
My answer got 6 votes up and none down, so it is fair to say that it reflects the thoughts of the community.
The answer gave six guidelines to follow, and the four first ones are very concrete.
In the deleted question you followed none of them.
Zero out of four.
I imagine the community would like it much more if you could make it four out of four.
Frankly, I would suggest using that answer as a checklist and making sure you always follow it — it might not be the best guide out there, but would certainly make your questions more warmly received here.

My suggestion is to forget about that old question and reask it.
Start fresh, but also do fresh:
Follow the given instructions, and I am sure it will be received better.

I agree with fdb that there is a good question in there, but I agree with the voters that the presentation is less than optimal.