# How did 'folding' semantically shift to mean 'reply'?

Tags: discussion

I don't understand [etymologia - How did 'folding' semantically shift to mean 'reply'? - Latin Language Stack Exchange](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/13022/how-did-folding-semantically-shift-to-mean-reply?noredirect=1#comment23688_13022)

> I'm voting to close this as duplicate because the first part is taken word-for-word from the earlier question, with no real elaboration or change.

I wrote the last para. that distinguished my questions. What more ought I do? I just moved that last para. to the top.

Answer (score 2):

Five others have closed the question, so I cannot be sure of their reasons. I believe only the most highly voted reason is visible, so it is possible different people closed it for different reasons.

As to whether it is a duplicate: it is possible that voters felt the new question was too closely connected to warrant a new, separate question. Instead, if you wanted more information about a certain aspect of your question, you could edit your question to explain which exact etymological step you would like more information on.

In addition, such a specific question about etymology may be considered unanswerable: we don't know much about the semantic development of most words, and our best sources, etymological and large dictionaries, usually don't provide any such details, presumably because the latter would be mostly speculative. Indeed, my own answers on etymology are usually speculative, as you can see.

Lastly, some may object to the question based on its format. Joonas has made [some good suggestions](https://latin.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/412/how-can-i-make-on-topic-questions-comparing-philosophical-terms-and-their-latin).

Comment: I edited this now. Please re-open?